# Primefaces grapicImage dosen't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hey i have a problem with the following line of codes

```
<b:column col-md="4" col-xs="12" col-lg="4">
            <b:thumbnail style="background-color:#6AB7FF;">
            <p:graphicImage name="Desert.jpg" library="img" alt="Bild von auditcheck 4.0"></p:graphicImage>
                <f:facet name="caption">     
                    <h3>auditcheck 4.0</h3>
                    <p>Kennen Sie schon auditcheck 4.0.</p>
                    <p><strong>Überprüfen Sie Ihre Kunden direkt und in Echtzeit mit unsere Web Lösung.</strong></p>
                    <p>
                        <b:button look="primary" value="Jetzt Informieren" />           
                    </p>
                </f:facet>
            </b:thumbnail>
        </b:column>
```

The image isn't show. 
My Web.xml looks like this:

```
[...]
<context-param>
    <param-name>jaxax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
</context-param>
[...]
```

So nothing happens...only the 'alt' tag is showing
All folders are correct implements - Other frames works fine.

Comment: Doesn't work is to vague. Care to investigate more and elaborate?

Comment: Probably because you have a typo.  **Its: javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY** not **jaxax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY**

Comment: @esteban rincon - thx for the comment. That solved my problem